# Conflicting type declarations between testcafe and jest - Can I redeclare types within a folder to prevent conflict?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, automated-tests, testcafe

Due to an issue between Jest and Testcafe, there's a conflict in type declarations, meaning the `test` function they both use resolves to Jests type definition.

**Jest: node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts**

```
declare var test: jest.It;
```

**Testcafe: node_modules/testcafe/ts-defs/index.d.ts**

```
declare const test: TestFn;
```

**Resulting in:**

> Property 'typeText' does not exist on type 'DoneCallback'.

`DoneCallback` is part of Jests index.d.ts file, not testcafes.  This is a perfectly valid testcafe test.

```
test("This is a testcafe test...", async t => {
    await t.typeText(SomeInput, "hello");
}
```

To get around this, I've found I can add `declare const test: TestFn;` into my individual testcafe files.  However, there are approximately 15-20 of them.  Is there a way that I can declare this elsewhere outside on my files?  Maybe within the folder containing the test files itself, as to not conflict with my other jest tests?

Alternatively, if there are any better approaches, I'd be very interested in hearing them.

Thanks

Comment: The following seems to be the same issue, however, I don't want to exclude my testcafe files in my tsconfig - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341503/how-do-i-resolve-a-type-conflict-between-testcafe-and-jest-cannot-redeclare-b

Comment: I would love to help you with this issue, but it's hard to determine its cause without an example. Could you please provide a sample project (including all configuration files like tsconfig.json, package.json, etc.) that I could run on my side to reproduce the error?

It would be ideal if you create an issue in our GitHub repository at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/ with a detailed description of your scenario and include the example.